# How to use the functions of the imported module in current module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a module named test1.js which is being exported default as test1.

```js
//test1.js

function fun1(){
    console.log("this is test function 1");
}

function fun2(){
    console.log("this is test function 2");
}

export default 'test1';
```

Then another file is there named mod1.js importing test1.js as follwing-

```js
import test1 from './test1.js';
test1.fun1();
```

I tried to access the function of test1.js module using the '.' which is not correct. I don't know how to access this kind of functions, even is it possible or not?

Comment: you've only exported the literal string `'test1'`. There are lots of ways of importing and exporting, but to make your code that imports from `test1.js` work as written, try `export default { fun1, fun 2}`

Comment: as ever [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#exporting_module_features) has a good guide to how import/export works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax of exporting is wrong. You can use curly braces `{}` to export:

```
function fun1(){
    console.log("this is test function 1");
}

function fun2(){
    console.log("this is test function 2");
}

export {fun1, fun2};
```

Similarly you can import the same way but you need to add on the file name:

```
import {fun1, fun2} from 'test1.js';
fun1();
fun2();
```

For Reference: https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: If there is a long number of functions in the module then what to do? Is there other efficient way to handle that situation ?

Comment: You can put export before every function you want to export. `export function fun1(){}`

Comment: So basically what stuff my code was exporting as 'test1' ?

Answer (score 0):

The export is incorrect. You need to export the functions as below:

```js
    //test1.js

    function fun1(){
        console.log("this is test function 1");
    }
    
    function fun2(){
        console.log("this is test function 2");
    }

    export default { fun1, fun2 }
```

Since it's a default export you may import it by any name in mod1.js

```js
import test1 from './test1.js';
test1.fun1();
```